# capture video without UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to capture video in my app without using UIImagePickerController.
I want to be able to display it too on the iPhone screen ib the same time.

I tried to find an article and tutorial on how to do it but I couldn't find it.

Does apple allow to do stuff like this or only use the UIImagePickerController?

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [AVCam](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html) sample from the Apple developer site. It shows you everything you need to know.

Also read about the [AVFoundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188) framework.